# Htaccess rewirte permission for invalid file extension in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I don't know this old question or not.i have google for a hour,but i cant find the solution.

In htaccess we can redirect 404(designed,not default) when invalid file.

For example:

```
https://www.example.com/tedgfsst.php
```

If I enter invalid file extension, than need to redirect 404 page

for example:

```
https://www.example.com/tedgfsst.eg
```

or

```
https://www.example.com/tedgfsst.cr
```

Comment: Do you have htaccess directives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the answer to rewrite the invalid file extension redirect to 404 error page.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /|(/[^.]*|[a-z]|[0-9]\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
```